# What to do to prevent or overcome bank interest (riba)?

Tags: practical-islam, riba, banking

I'm working abroad and my bank account is in USD currency. Nonetheless, the bank does not offer interest-free banking for some reason (said that its a system generated for each deposit I receive). Even when questioned to take it out, they refused to do so explaining that they cannot change the system functionality just for few people.

However, my home country bank does Islamic banking where I have lifted out the interest part where I don't even get a single penny as interests anymore. Now my question is;

- How can I handle this situation knowing that the interests are still in my bank account as I do not want them to be left in my account.
- I do know that even burning money is not accepted (or correct me if I'm wrong).
- Even if I withdraw money, AFAIK, I cannot offer to anyone or to do charity service. Moreover, if I leave this earth with that money in hand by any event, I cannot think of such a consequence.

The carelessness of these little things by us is, what brings out great danger to after life (at least that is what I think so). So, please advise what sort actions can I take to prevent or to overcome this?

Please also do note, that our company handles accounts in few banks which they are all having interests and it is nearly difficult to changes banks provided that we are expats.

Comment: You just mentioned three claims in your bullet points with no reference at all, and by your logic you indicate that there is no way to get rid of interest and that it would keep accumulating

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/20695 &&  https://islamqa.info/en/292

Answer (score 1):

There are Muslim charities to which you can donate to "cleanse your income" in Islamic ways.  For example, [Islamic Aid](https://www.islamicaid.com/bank-interest-money/) write:

> Can I donate interest money to Islamic Aid?
>
> Yes, you can. We will use your money to support our work helping save lives of the poor and needy **but will not use it on projects where interest should not be spent, such as the construction of mosques.**

[image: Donation type: Interest money]

Another example is [MuslimAid.org.au](http://www.muslimaid.org.au/):

[image: What is interest? Giving and taking interest are both decisively impermissible in Islam. Similarly, it is impermissible to consume unlawfully earned money. Cleanse your income received from interest.]

On [their FAQ page](http://www.muslimaid.org.au/about-us/about-muslim-aid-(8)), they write:

> Q: How are projects selected and who confirms that the projects are as per Islamic requirements?
>
> ...
>
> One of these standards is the design and creation of the world’s first **Shariah Compliant Donation system** which we have implemented into our website and mobile app. This system was designed to adhere various Islamic Fiqh guidelines as to how money can be distributed depending on where the money was derived. **For instance, if someone has money which may have been accumulated from an interest bearing account, these funds cannot be given to say, orphans, they must follow our shariah model and be placed/distributed to the Islamically approved and accepted fund pool.**

(I declare that I have no affiliation with these charities.)

Comment: Maybe you should add that not all kinds of charity is allowed as http://legacy.quran.com/2/275 indicates that one shouldn't consume the money of riba, in Arabic ya'kuluna refers to eating, so in first place scholars don't allow spending money of riba for food unfortunately this is only what I've heard or asked scholars about myself, so I have no backup.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can withdraw the "illegitimate interest/money" immediately, and spend that money to help in muslims' public utilities. You should then stop using any interest-giving bank as that's "Riba" forbidden in islam.

Comment: Again answers starting with AFAIK is not the kind of answer we expect here see [answer].